# How to find the latest folder in a directory and then make a full path accordingly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

I have a directory which will have some folders and some files within it. Suppose this is my current directory as shown below with `pwd` command -

```
david@slc4b03c:/bat/data/snapshot$ pwd
/bat/data/snapshot
```

And I am logged into `machineA`.

This `/bat/data/snapshot` directory will have some folders and some files within it as shown below -

```
david@slc4b03c:/bat/data/snapshot$ ls -lt
total 22400264
drwxr-xr-x 2 cronusapp app   102400 2013-12-22 04:01 20131222
drwxr-xr-x 2 cronusapp app   102400 2013-12-16 03:00 20131215
-rw-r--r-- 1 cronusapp app 26412620 2013-12-13 02:04 weekly_003_5.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 cronusapp app 26492037 2013-12-13 02:02 weekly_003_5.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 cronusapp app 26480695 2013-12-13 02:02 weekly_003_5.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 cronusapp app 26475266 2013-12-13 02:02 weekly_003_5.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 cronusapp app 26471366 2013-12-13 02:02 weekly_003_5.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 cronusapp app 26455311 2013-12-13 02:02 weekly_003_5.data
```

So the two folders I have is `20131222` and `20131215` as shown above.. Now I want to extract the latest folder from it, which will be `20131222` as it is more recent as compared to `20131215` and then make a full path like this -

```
/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/
```

As I need to use this full path while doing the scp from that machine to another machine,

Below is my shell script in which I have hardcoded the recent path currently with `20131222` but in general, I need to make the full path by seeing which folder is the latest one by using the below shell script..

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly LOCATION=/bat/data/snapshot

scp david@slc4b03c.slc.host.com:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_003_5.data /data01/primary/.
```

The above shell script I won't be running from the machineA. I will be running from different machine, let' say it is `machineB`.

Is it possible to do this in shell script?

Comment: Your listing seems to show the same folder name appearing 6 times (with some size differences); is that an editing error, or do they end with 0-5 blanks, or something else similar?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Exactly, that was by mistake while editing.. Sorry about that..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Simple but unreliable solution

```
dir=$(ls -dt1 "$LOCATION"/*/ | head -n1)
scp "david@slc4b03c.slc.host.com:$dir"/weekly_003_5.data /data01/primary/.
```

The above would fail if the name of the most recent directory contains a newline or other difficult characters.

If you want to restrict the directory name to be in the form of a date (YYYYMMDD), as per your examples, then try:

```
dir=$(ls -dt1 "$LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ | head -n1)
```

For more info on the problems with using `ls` in this way, see:

- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [Is there a reason why ls does not have a --zero or -0 option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112125/is-there-a-reason-why-ls-does-not-have-a-zero-or-0-option)
- [ls authors: "ls is really a tool for direct consumption by a human"](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2014-02/msg00005.html)

#### More Robust solution (GNU tools required)

This code uses `find` with NUL-separated output to handle difficult file names:

```
dir=$(find "$LOCATION" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' |sort -znr | sed -zE 's/^[^ ]+ //;q')
```

Comment: Hello,

I'm using the "More Robust solution" and it works correctly, in that it identifies the most recently created directory.

However, I also get the following warning when running the script:
warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @VeeDub That sounds like one of your programs doesn't understand NUL-separated strings.  What OS are you using?

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @VeeDub OK.  The Ubuntu programs should understand nul bytes.  Everything should work.  Could there be a stray (invisible) character in your script file?  Check it with a hex dump utility.  Also, could the error be coming from a different line in your script?  Try running it under `bash -x` to see where the error appears and how bash evaluates each string.

Comment: Believe the script file is good.
Test output below
#!/bin/bash

REAR_BACKUP_PATH=/media/zen/REAR-000/rear/Ubuntu-DR6/

dir=$(find "$REAR_BACKUP_PATH" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' |sort -znr | sed -zE 's/^[^ ]+ //;q')

$ bash -x ./find_most_recent_directory.sh 
+ REAR_BACKUP_PATH=/media/zen/REAR-000/rear/Ubuntu-DR6/
++ find /media/zen/REAR-000/rear/Ubuntu-DR6/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0'
++ sort -znr
++ sed -zE 's/^[^ ]+ //;q'
./find_most_recent_directory.sh: line 5: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Comment: @VeeDub As best  I can tell (SO has run all the lines together in your script), our `dir$(find....)` command is on line 3 but the error message says the problem is on line 5.  Is that correct?  If not, could you post your code somewhere so I could see it unmolested?

Comment: I find the comments annoying on two levels. First, all the formatting is removed. Second, there is a limit on the number of characters that can be entered. I am happy to post somewhere else, where I can properly show the test code and output.

Where do you suggest?

Comment: @VeeDub An online search led me to https://codeshare.io/ .  There are probably other sites as well.

Comment: You can find the code here https://codeshare.io/xvok3M

Comment: Example output: ./find_most_recent_directory.sh: line 5: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
/media/zen/REAR-000/rear/Ubuntu-DR6/20220711.1556

Comment: @VeeDub Thanks much for your patience.  I was able to reproduce the problem.  I added a `tr` command to fix it.  Try `dir=$(find "$BACKUP_PATH" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' |sed -E --null-data 's/^[^ ]+ //;q' | tr -d '\000')` and let me know.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks, for sharing the original code and taking the time to research and provide this update

Comment: Unfortunately, I replied too soon. While the new code doesn't produce an error/warning, it doesn't return the most recent directory. So there is a flaw with the update

Comment: I'll put some more info in the codeshare above

Comment: @VeeDub Thank you for the updated codeshare.  I copied your your script (repairing line 5 which gets truncated in codeshare) and recreated your directories with your timestamps.  When I run the code, I get the correct result.  I don't yet have any guesses for why our results differ.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. I'll continue to use the original code on the current system, as that works. If I end up using the script on another system, I'll try the updated code and see if I get a different result. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do this, but the way I'd do as a quick & dirty is to use a combination of `find` and `sort` and `tail`:

```
dir=`find $LOCATION -type d | sort | tail -1`
```

By specifying `$LOCATION` as the path for `find`, you'll automatically get the directory prepended to your output, which should let `sort` and `tail` give you the answer without any further interpolation of current directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot Palpatim for the suggestion. Can we also verify that whatever value of `dir` we are getting is in the form of `YYYYMMDD` If it is in this form, then only I can say that I need to use this dir..

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for latest directory on specific directory, please use below command to get latest director and assign on any variable

```
ls | sort | tail -1
```